Movie ends with wall mounted alien hand moving. Poison lump on hand
50s to 60s, black and white? Alien attack movie. Alien hand mounted and hung on wall. Large lump on back of hand holds poison. Long finger nails may release poison when they dig in. Camera pans to hand and it starts to move. Freaked me out as a kid. Gotta see it again

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0050545/?

Perhaps "The Eye Creatures", the 1967 remake of "Invasion of the Saucer Men"? I haven't seen the film in a long time, but I recall that the remake's alien had an eye on the back of its severed hand.

@StanleyWebb The full title, due to an editing error, is "Attack of the the [sic] Eye Creatures".

As Stanley noted in a comment, there is a hand very much like this in the film Invasion of the Saucer Men (1957). The poison, however, I don't believe is in the film.
See image here:


The Saucer Men had retractable hypodermic claws that delivered alcohol as venom. The film was for chuckles, so the venom mainly just made characters drunk, but I believe one victim died of alien alcohol poisoning.
